# How to render a template outside of a web request in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, templates, mojolicious

Is there a way to use the Mojolicious rendering engine to render a template outside of a web request?

Comment: You should accept the solution of Tudor since he made some effort and it helped you

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I would love to. How does one "accept the solution"? I don't see any button or such to let me do so.

Comment: ahh I just realized I have to click on the checkmark. sorry very non-intuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes

```
use Mojolicious::Renderer;

my $renderer = Mojolicious::Renderer->new;

push @{renderer->paths}, '/path/to/your/templates';

my $template = $renderer->get_data_template({
    template       => 'foo/bar',
    format         => 'html',
    handler        => 'epl'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it has to be something simple, but the render docs just don't show the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more comprehensive (and more up to date) solution that allows the full use of all the rendering plugins that available with the full Mojolicious stack.

```
use Mojolicious;

unless (@ARGV) {
    die "$0: <template base name> [key value pairs]\n";
}

my $app = Mojolicious->new(secrets => ['ignored']);
my $c = $app->build_controller;
my $r = $app->renderer;

push @{$r->paths}, './templates';          # directory containing templates
$c->app->log->level('fatal');


my $template = shift;                      # template base name e.g. 'index' which looks up ./templates/index.html.ep
$c->stash(shift, shift) while @ARGV >= 2;  # add extra parameters into cache
my $out = $c->render_to_string($template);
print $out if $out;

exit 0;
```